# Setting an element's height to the height available in the viewport?

Tags: html, css

My element's height increases depending on what the user does with it. If I give it a wrapper div, and give that div an explicit pixel height and `overflow:auto`, it works as I would want it to (when the element becomes bigger than the height of its parent, it doesn't increase the size of the parent). I want the wrapper div to be as big as the space available on the page, but not allow it to expand beyond that. Giving it `height:100%` doesn't work, it just gets bigger. Giving it `height:100vh` also doesn't work because there are other elements on the page and so the size is too big.

I want the wrapper div to be able to expand until it becomes too big for the viewport (which `height:100vh` would achieve if it were not for the other elements on the page).

Basically I'm looking for something like `height : amount of available space in the viewport`.

Comment: You've been member long enough to know to post the html/css you have so far.

Comment: That said, set `max-height`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
var offset = $('#gridWrapper').offset().top;
$('#gridWrapper').height(viewportHeight - offset);
```

I execute the same stuff again on resize. `gridWrapper` is the id of the wrapping div.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `height:80vh` or similar depends on the height of your other elements

Comment: I was thinking about that, but unfortunately, the elements at the top are a fixed pixel amount, meaning that something like `80vh` wouldn't always be right.

Answer (score 0):

```
function resizeElement() {
var height = $(window).height();
var neededHeight = (70 * height) / 100; //If you want 70% of the viewport
neededHeight = parseInt(neededHeight) + 'px';
$("div").css('height',neededHeight);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
resizeElement();
$(window).bind('resize', resizeElement);
});
```

You can try this. You may need to check what value do you get in var height. Depending on that you can append px or not in neededHeight. This is basically the logic.

Comment: I don't want the element to take up the entire page's height though.

Comment: You can then do a percentage count. Something like var neededHeight= (70 * height) / 100; neededHeight = parseInt(neededHeight) + 'px'; if you want 70% of the viewport for example

Comment: Thanks, but a percent of the viewport wouldn't have done it, since the other elements on the page were a fixed pixel size, so depending on the resolution of the user's screen, the percent of the viewport needed would change. I found a solution in the end anyway. :)